# One template to std::get them all

Tags: c++, templates, tuples, c++20, c++-concepts

For use in other templates, I want to have a function like std::get for a tuple which returns an instance of a default type when the get call is invalid; the kind of

```
template<size_t I, typename T> auto get_or(T const& t)
{
  // Pseudocode
  return ("if std::get<I>(t) is valid") ? std::get<I>(t) : std::monostate{};
}
```

But I failed, and I wonder whether it is due to my lack of experience with C++ concepts, or maybe a bug in the compiler (Visual Studio 2022 version 17.8.4), or maybe it simply is not possible.

This is what I tried:

I defined a type trait and a concept that tell me whether T is a tuple:

```
template<typename T> struct is_tuple : std::false_type {};
template<typename... Ts> struct is_tuple<std::tuple<Ts...>> : std::true_type {};

namespace test_concepts
{
    template<typename T> concept is_tuple = requires { ::is_tuple<T>::value; };
}
```

Next, I want to answer the question "given a tuple t and a compile-time constant I, would `std::get<I>(t)` be valid?

```
template<size_t I, typename T> constexpr bool can_get (T const&) { return false; }
template<size_t I, typename T> requires test_concepts::is_tuple<T>
constexpr bool can_get(T const& t)
{
    return (I < std::tuple_size_v<std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(t)>>);
}
namespace test_concepts
{
    template<size_t I, typename T> concept can_get = requires(T t) { ::can_get<I>(t); };
}


// Test code
std::tuple<> t0;
std::tuple<int> t1;
std::tuple<double, float> t2;

static_assert(!can_get<0>(t0)); static_assert(!can_get<1>(t0)); static_assert(!can_get<2>(t0));
static_assert( can_get<0>(t1)); static_assert(!can_get<1>(t1)); static_assert(!can_get<2>(t1));
static_assert( can_get<0>(t2)); static_assert( can_get<1>(t2)); static_assert(!can_get<2>(t2));
```

This works. However, when I do the final step, I receive a compile-time error.

```
template<size_t I, typename T> auto get_or(T const& t)
{
    return std::monostate{};
}
template<size_t I, typename T> requires test_concepts::can_get<I, T>
auto get_or(T const& t)
{
    return std::get<I>(t);
}

// Test code
std::tuple<> t0;
std::tuple<int> t1;
auto x00 = get_or<0>(t0);
// I expect x00 to be of type std::monostate, but instead this error is displayed:
// error C2338: static_assert failed: 'tuple index out of bounds'
auto x10 = get_or<0>(t1);
// Context help shows that x10 is of type int as expected
auto x11 = get_or<1>(t1);
// error C2338 again for x11
```

Any ideas? - Thanks!

Comment: the question would be more accessible if the [mcve] would be one block of code including a `main` that one can easily copy and paste to reproduce the compiler error

Comment: Your concept `test_concepts::can_get` only requires, that `::can_get<I>(t);` compiles, not that it returns true

Comment: Same for the other concept. `requires{ expr }` doesn't check if `expr` is truthy, it checks if it's valid. So both of your concepts are always true.

You want simply `concept Name = expr;`, without `requires{ ... }` (or `requires{ requires expr; }` to check for truthy-ness *and* treat errors in the expression itself as `false`).

Comment: Also writing `is_tuple` like this is a bad idea, because there are other types that also support `std::get` and the rest of the tuple protocol (`std::array`, `std::pair`, `std::complex`). Use `requires{std::tuple_size<T>::value;}` instead (not `std::tuple_size_v`, that's not SFINAE-friendly).

Comment: Oh, and also instead of `std::get<i>(t)` use `using std::get; get<i>(t)` to support non-std types which define `get` in their own namespace (see e.g. [structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) type requirements).

Comment: Thank you for all these valuable comments. With your help, I finally managed to make my code work. However, I have one more question.
If ```requires { expr }``` validates that ```expr``` can compile, then why does the following code give an error "tuple index out f bounds":
```
template<size_t I, typename T> requires requires { std::get<I>(T{}); }
auto get_or_2(T const& tpl)
{
    return std::get<I>(tpl);
}
int main()
{
    std::tuple<> t0;
    auto y00 = get_or_2<0>(t0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry the formatting of my previous comment is messed up, and I forgot to insert the generic definition: ```template<size_t I, typename T> auto get_or_2(T const& tpl) { return std::monostate{}; }```

Comment: Because `std::get` isn't SFINAE-friendly. There's no good reason why, it's just poorly designed in this regard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misusing the `requires`-clause.

The `requires`-clause only checks the validity of the expression without actually evaluating it, so your concept is always satisfied.

You can use nested `requires` to evaluate the expression, e.g.

```
template<typename T> concept is_tuple = requires { requires ::is_tuple<T>::value; };
```

Or even simpler

```
template<typename T> concept is_tuple = ::is_tuple<T>::value;
```

The same goes for `test_concepts::can_get`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the contributors of comments and answers, I managed to create a working solution. The `is_tuple` template is not longer necessary, and I renamed `get_or` into `get_or_default` because it now has another parameter for the default type.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <xutility>


#pragma region can_get

template<size_t I, typename T>
struct can_get : std::false_type {};

template<size_t I, typename T> requires requires { std::tuple_size<T>::value; } && (I < std::tuple_size<T>::value)
struct can_get<I, T> : std::true_type {};

namespace test_concepts
{
    template<size_t I, typename T>
    concept can_get = ::can_get<I, T>::value;
}

#pragma region can_get


#pragma region get_or_default

template<size_t I, typename DEFAULT = std::monostate, typename T>
auto get_or_default(T const& tpl)
{
    return DEFAULT{};
}

template<size_t I, typename DEFAULT = std::monostate, typename T> requires test_concepts::can_get<I, T>
auto get_or_default(T const& tpl)
{
    using std::get;
    return get<I>(tpl);
}

#pragma endregion get_or_default


int main()
{
    std::tuple<> t0;
    std::tuple<int> t1;
    std::tuple<double, float> t2;

    static_assert(!can_get<0, int>::value); // 'int' is not tuple-like, tuple_size<int> is not defined

    static_assert(!can_get<0, decltype(t0)>::value);
    static_assert(!can_get<1, decltype(t0)>::value);
    static_assert(!can_get<2, decltype(t0)>::value);
    static_assert( can_get<0, decltype(t1)>::value);
    static_assert(!can_get<1, decltype(t1)>::value);
    static_assert(!can_get<2, decltype(t1)>::value);
    static_assert( can_get<0, decltype(t2)>::value);
    static_assert( can_get<1, decltype(t2)>::value);
    static_assert(!can_get<2, decltype(t2)>::value);

    static_assert(!can_get<0, std::tuple<   >>::value);
    static_assert( can_get<0, std::tuple<int>>::value);

    auto x00 = get_or_default<0, int  >(t0);        static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(x00), int           >);
    auto x10 = get_or_default<0, void*>(t1);        static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(x10), int           >);
    auto x11 = get_or_default<1, void*>(t1);        static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(x11), void*         >);
    auto x20 = get_or_default<0       >(t2);        static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(x20), double        >);
    auto x21 = get_or_default<1       >(t2);        static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(x21), float         >);
    auto x22 = get_or_default<2       >(t2);        static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(x22), std::monostate>);

    auto xxx = get_or_default<0, nullptr_t>("hi");  static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(xxx), nullptr_t     >); // not tuple-like

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks good. You could use `if constexpr` to combine `get_or_default` to a single function. Also `can_get` can be shortened to `template<size_t I, typename T> concept can_get = I < std::tuple_size<T>::value;` (concepts automatically return false on SFAINE failure), or `if constexpr (requires{requires I < std::tuple_size<T>::value;})` if you wanted to avoid the concept entirely.

Comment: You mean like ```if constexpr (requires { I < std::tuple_size<T>::value; }) return get<I>(tpl); else return DEFAULT{};```? This gives me error 'tuple index out of bounds'. Maybe MSVC is not standard compliant with respect to "concepts automatically return false on SFAINE failure"? But still in the ```can_get``` concept, the trick works!

Comment: `if constexpr (I < std::tuple_size<T>::value)`. `requires` check expression, and does not evaluate the value.

Comment: @h.s. No, with two `requires` exactly as I spelled it.

Comment: @Jarod42 This would give a hard fail on non-tuples, while OP wants `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Your pseudocode

```
return ("if std::get<I>(t) is valid") ? std::get<I>(t) : std::monostate{};
```

would be:

```
template <size_t I, typename Tuple>
constexpr auto get_or(Tuple const& t)
{
    if constexpr (requires { std::get<I>(t); }) { // Hard error :-(
        return std::get<I>(t);
    } else {
        return std::monostate{};
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, `std::get` is not SFINAE-friendly, and so produces hard errors, instead of failing the concept.

You might then check the precondition yourself instead:

```
template <size_t I, typename Tuple>
constexpr auto get_or(Tuple const& t)
{
    if constexpr (I < std::tuple_size_v<Tuple>) {
        return std::get<I>(t);
    } else {
        return std::monostate{};
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xvWf99f4h)

Comment: "Unfortunately, std::get is not SFINAE-friendly, and so produces hard errors" - that matches my observations. Is that so by design, or is it an error in the implementation of std::get?

Comment: If it is an error, it would be in the specifications.